# Turn a string into a method and argument list

Tags: ruby

I have a string:

```
input # => 'make_me sandwich noodles coffee'
```

I want to call `make_me` method with arguments `sandwich`, `noodles`, `coffee`:

```
make_me(sandwich, noodles, coffee)
```

I know of using `split`, and using the first array element as the method name and the remains as the arguments. Is there a better way?

Comment: coding styles may vary, but i believe, the solution you've described is enough good, concise and only available approach.

Comment: i felt there could be a better way :(

Answer (score 2):

Sounds dangerous but here you go:

```
command_with_args = input.split(" ")
send(command_with_args[0], *command_with_args[1..3])
```

Comment: I totally agree when you say dangerous, but have validated command_with_args[0] with defined names.

Comment: You can unpack the array in the assignment `command, *args = input.split(" "); send(command, *args)`

Comment: refactoring your answer maybe you should edit `send(command_with_args[0], *command_with_args[1..-1])`.

Answer (score 1):

Credits to @akuhn and @Sooraj, Briefing that we need to use `split()`

```
cmd, *args = gets.chomp().split(" ")
send(cmd, *args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually mean strings:

```
send(*input.split(" "))
```

If you intended each argument to be a method, then:

```
method, *args = input.split(" ")
send(method, *args.map{|arg| send(arg)})
```